# How works the pseudo-variable $this in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, this

I understand the official explanation about the **$this**: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

But if I try to understand what is the object reference in this case of symfony, I don't know who is it, for example:

Each time when you need to return the theme, use this:

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('foo/bar.html.twig', array());
    }
```

Or when you generate a some form:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        // Create the form

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('name', TextType::class)
                ->add('email', EmailType::class)
                ->add('subject', TextType::class)
                ->add('message', TextareaType::class)
                ->add('send', SubmitType::class)
                ->getForm();
}
```

But who is exactly the object $this? and if working with other word or value that is not $this, only for try to understand better.

Comment: There is nothing magic about it, it's still a instance of your class.

Comment: Take a look at the Symfony base controller class: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php That is where the methods render and createFormBuilder are defined.  Might make it a bit easier to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking where are located the methods called by `$this` in your controller, take a look at the `extends` statement of your controller (just after class declaration).

All your controllers extends (by default) the [FrameworkBundle Controller](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Controller/Controller.php), also you can access all of the inherited methods, such as `createForm`, `render`, `getDoctrine`, `generateUrl`.

The parent `Controller` extends from `ContainerAware` (Dependency Injection), it allows you to access and use `services`.
Most of the methods I listed are just shortcuts of services methods.

i.e. `$this->generateUrl(/*params*/)` is equal to `$this->container->get('router')->generate(/*params/*)`

Answer (score 0):

In that case $this references an instance of the object eg. you are in a controller, then the $this variable references the current instance of the controller that you are in, and you can access all the methods that the class itself has and all the methods of the extended class in this case the base controller and so on in the inheritance hierarchy.

You can read this question to get more clarity.

[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

`$this` is how instances of a class in refer to themselves in PHP.

```
class Person
  private $name;

  public function __construct($name){
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  public function getName($name){
    $this->name = $name;
  }
end
```

When you create a instance of the class with `$foo = new Person('Max');`. `$this`  referrers to the new instance you are creating. When you use `$this` in a controller - this refers to the controller itself.

In natural language its like saying `my`.